# Find a a special ascii in string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove

> \x1b(B\x1b[m

in a string, but whenever I try using strip("\x1b(B\x1b[m") it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to ask for that literal string instead of using the expression it is.

Comment: Is the character sequence at the end of the string? Because `strip` only works on the ends of strings. Did you mean to use `replace`?

Comment: you're absolutely right.. thank you for the reminder!